# Angular 6: Clicking from component causes href value to add on URL

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and stuck in following problem:

I have a tabbed UI

My link:

```
<li>
  <a href="#referrals" id="tab-opinions" data-toggle="tab" target="_self" #referrals> 
   <span class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
   <span class="hidden-xs">Referrals</span> 
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#opinions" id="tab-opinions" data-toggle="tab" target="_self" #opinions> 
   <span class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
   <span class="hidden-xs">Opinions</span> 
  </a>
</li>
```

Corresponding tab content:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="referrals">
     <referral-list [data]="data"></referral-list>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="opinions">
     <doctor-opinion-list [data]="data"></doctor-opinion-list>
</div>
```

In my component:

```
@ViewChild("opinions") private opinions;
@ViewChild("referrals") private referrals;

...
...

/* Highlights a particular tab with given id */
highlightTab(tabId) {
  if (["referrals"].indexOf(tabId) > -1) {
    this.referrals.nativeElement.click();
  } else if (["opinions"].indexOf(tabId) > -1) {
    this.opinions.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

Current URL is:

```
/dashboard/patient/view/1
```

If I click on tab itself, everything works fine. But if I use statement like this:

```
highlightTab('referrals');
```

It changes the URL to:

```
http://localhost:4200/#referrals
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Any more code required?

Comment: The issue is with the `href` attribute of the anchor tags. like: `href="#referrals"`. Probably your `a` is very small so when your click manually, you don't click over the `anchor`. Remove the `hrefs` you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

you should not use href it will reload the page Use fragment and make sure you enable anchor scrolling in routerModule

**router.module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {        
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
    })
```

**component.html**

```
<li>
  <a  [fragment]="'referrals'" id="tab-opinions" data-toggle="tab" target="_self" #referrals> 
   <span class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
   <span class="hidden-xs">Referrals</span> 
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a [fragment]="'opinions'" id="tab-opinions" data-toggle="tab" target="_self" #opinions> 
   <span class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
   <span class="hidden-xs">Opinions</span> 
  </a>
</li>
```

Inject Router and use navigate method to navigate between route instead of using ViewChild

```
constructor( private router: Router ) {}
}
highlightTab(tabId) {
  if (["referrals"].indexOf(tabId) > -1) {
    this.router.navigate( [ 'path name' ], { fragment: 'referrals' } )
  } else if (["opinions"].indexOf(tabId) > -1) {
    this.router.navigate( [ 'path name' ], { fragment: 'opinions' } )
  }
}
```